# Is juju "relation-get" command works in "relation-broken" hook?

Tags: juju

I need to get the database user details from the DB charm, for this I have used the `relation-get` command in my `db-relation-changed` and `db-relation-broken` charms. The relation get command is working in the `db-relation-changed` hook but not in the `db-relation-broken` hook.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't read or write relation settings in a *-relation-broken hook. You can relation-get and relation-set in *-relation-joined and *-relation-changed. You can relation-get but NOT relation-set in *-relation-departed. And in *-relation-broken you can do neither.

More info on relations here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-relations-in-depth

Comment: @sun123, another way to say what Tim said is: do it in relation-departed.  If Tim answered your question, please mark it as the answer, so that you both get credit for it.  You get reputation points for closing it.